# How to create a scroll view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to create a simple scroll view when clicking a button in Xcode?

I have assigned the button and gave `IBAction` as press, 
what to code to make a scroll view on this action?

```
 -(IBAction)press
 {

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a UIScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998336/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add UIScrollView in UIView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035115/add-uiscrollview-in-uiview-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing UIScrollView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909347/implementing-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add uiscrollview programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186439/add-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating UIScrollView Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223707/creating-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.h` file you must add delegate definition to your class declaration - something like this:

```
@interface someClass : NSObject <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In `.m` write somethink like this:

```
 -(IBAction)press
 {
    UIScrollView *_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.delegate = nil;

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
}
```

That's all! :)