# Programmatically setting UIScrollView Orientation

Tags: uiscrollview, orientation, landscape, ios5.1

Is here any way to set UIScrollview orientation by coding? Actually I am creating scrollview programmatically and want to set its orientation landscape. I can't find any way on google and apple's docs.

Comment: check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998336/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Comment: This link does not help about orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With scrollviews, you don't give them an orientation exactly. You set their frame and their content size. So if you set the frame to 1024 x 768 and the content size is 3000 x 768, the scrollview will automatically allow scrolling horizontally. And because you set the frame to a landscape ratio/size, the scrollview will be in a landscape "orientation." Pseudo code below to help.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(3000, 768)];
```

Let me know if this doesn't help and I can elaborate or help further.