# Add UIScrollView in UIView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a question how to add UIScrollView in UIView, so that the UIScrollView could work properly.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, container.frame.size.width/2, container.frame.size.height/2)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * container.frame.size.width/2;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, container.frame.size.width, container.frame.size.height)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
    [awesomeView release];
}
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(container.frame.size.width/2 * numberOfViews, container.frame.size.height);
[container addSubview:scroll];
```

Above code is from tutorial: http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/
But it doesn't work for me.

**EDIT:**

If you have a problem that you have set up a scrollview properly but it's not working, make sure that you are not overlaying with another UIView your scrollview. That was my problem.
**Solved!**

Comment: can u not see the red color scroll view?

Comment: I see first UIView screen colorWithRed:0.5/i.

Comment: guess, your awesomeView is of larger width and height than the scroll view itself..that means scroll view is getting added, try increasing the frame and content size of the scroll view.

Comment: i think your xOrigin caluclation is wrong, the awesomeView's ,must be overlapping

Comment: I can see the UIViews. I cant just scroll the UIScrollView.

Comment: you can post your solution as answer and accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a UIScrollView Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998336/how-to-create-a-uiscrollview-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to add UIScrollView on yourView :-

Step 1:

```
Delegate "UIScrollViewDelegate" to your ViewController.h

for example:
  @interface yourViewController:UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Step 2:

```
//create you UIScrollView
UIScrollView  *MyScrollVw= [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,320 ,480)]; 
MyScrollVw.delegate= self;
[MyScrollVw setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[MyScrollVw setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
MyScrollVw.scrollEnabled= YES;
MyScrollVw.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
[yourView addSubview:MyScrollVw];
MyScrollVw.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320 ,1500);//(width,height)
```

Step 3:

you want to implement the scrollView Delegates in ViewController.m

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   return imgView;
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did end decelerating");
   //do your code here
}   
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did scroll");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSLog(@"Did end dragging");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Did begin decelerating");
   //do your code here
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   NSLog(@"Did begin dragging");
   //do your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(container.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, container.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[container addSubview:scroll];
```

Add this line before your for loop.

Comment: It does not help. I can see the scrollview and it's content but I can't slide.